# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException Index 0 requested, with a size of 0 in Android

Tags: android, android-cursor

I have a activity where in the user can fill out from the spinners. But if the user didn't fill out any of this spinner and then click the Save Button, an AlertDialog must show.

However, it is not as I expected. When I click the Save Button, it shows an error: "***CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException Index 0 requested, with a size of 0***"

How can I resolve this kind of error?

**DatabaseHandler.java**

```
public Cursor getReport_DistrictCode(String district) 
{
    SQLiteDatabase dbSqlite = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = dbSqlite.query(Constants.TABLE_DISTRICT, new String[] 
            {Constants.DISTRICT_ID, Constants.DISTRICT_CODE,Constants.DISTRICT_NAME,Constants.DISTRICT_DESCRIPTION}, 
            Constants.DISTRICT_NAME+" = ?" , new String[]{district}, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    dbSqlite.close();
    return c;
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
spn_District.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View SelectedItem, int position, long id) 
        {
            int rowid = (int)parentView.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
            int districtId = rowid;
            if(districtId == 0)
            {
                List<String> Province = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(S_10th_IReportMain.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Province);
                spn_Province.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            List<String> Province = databaseHandler.setItemOnProvinceSpinner(districtId);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(S_10th_IReportMain.this, R.layout.spinnerattributecell, Province) {
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
                {
                    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                    Typeface externalFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Gothic_Regular.TTF");
                    ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont);

                    return v;
                }

                public View getDropDownView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
                      View v =super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);

                     Typeface externalFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Gothic_Regular.TTF");
                     ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont);

                     return v;
                }
            };
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinnerdropdownitem);
            spn_Province.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }

    });
```

Implementation of my CursorAdapter to MainActivity.java

```
String District = spn_District.getSelectedItem().toString();
Cursor rDistrict = databaseHandler.getReport_DistrictCode(District);
String DistrictCode = rDistrict.getString(rDistrict.getColumnIndex(Constants.DISTRICT_CODE));
```

Comment: can you give implementation of your cursoradapter?

Comment: Hi @KapilVats, it is the last code attached

Comment: which line you are getting this error

Comment: It points on this line: String DistrictCode = rDistrict.getString(rDistrict.getColumnIndex(Constants.DISTRICT_CODE));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove this from your `getReport_DistrictCode`

```
if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
```

Instead just return the cursor and then after `Cursor rDistrict = databaseHandler.getReport_DistrictCode(District);`  , instead of doing a null check, add this check  `if(rDistrict.moveToFirst()){ // add your logic}`

Comment: Can you show a clear answer most especially on your last paragraph.

Comment: The cursor object will never be equal to null, but it can be empty (have 0 rows). If you need a check you can use if(cursor.getCount() > 0). Your code is failing because you assume that because your null check is in place that the cursor will not be empty.